# 3D Carousel Drifts Off Center While Scrolling

Tags: css, angular

I've been working on this 3D carousel that I've been trying to make from scratch instead of using a library. A lot of the code came from using generative AI to help me adapt this demo:
https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/carousel

into an angular component. I'm a beginner so was more or less improvising as I went using AI to try to understand and iterate on the code, and ended up with probably some hacky solutions to edge cases I ran into and whatnot.

Anyway, the main issue I have right now is the carousel drifts off center as you scroll to the right. I believe it has to do with how the shape of the carousel is constructed geometrically in the changeCarousel function and then rotated in the rotateCarousel function, but since I don't fully understand how each component affects the design, I haven't been able to tweak or change anything to get the carousel to not drift. It may also be an issue with the CSS, which the AI tried to fix using a transform-origin property to no avail. If anyone has any ideas how I could center the carousel and have it not drift, that would be greatly appreciated as I'm losing my mind :D thanks!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-iybccm?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Note: Once you complete a full rotation, it snaps position a bit, which is intentional as it fixed an earlier issue of reaching the end or beginning of the array of items being an edge case when scrolling.

I tried modifying a lot of the values in the changeCarousel and rotateCarousel functions to no avail. I then tried modifying some of the CSS properties. I've found that swapping the position property on .carousel to relative and the position property on .carousel__cell to absolute stops the carousel from drifting horizontally and the carousel is centered, but it puts the entire carousel on an oblique angle and it drifts vertically. This leads me to believe it's mostly if not entirely a CSS issue with the hodge podge of CSS properties I copy and pasted and how they interact. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.